# Missing and repeating number array from 1...n for very large inputs. Solution using properties of 1...n series. Overflow issues

Tags: c++, arrays, overflow

This is the code provided for https://www.interviewbit.com/problems/repeat-and-missing-number-array/ by the same website:

```
vector<int> repeatedNumber(const vector<int> &V) {
   long long sum = 0;
   long long squareSum = 0;
   long long temp;
   for (int i = 0; i < V.size(); i++) {
       temp = V[i];
       sum += temp;
       sum -= (i + 1);
       squareSum += (temp * temp);
       squareSum -= ((long long)(i + 1) * (long long)(i + 1));
   }
   // sum = A - B
   // squareSum = A^2 - B^2 = (A - B)(A + B)
   // squareSum / sum = A + B
   squareSum /= sum;

   // Now we have A + B and A - B. Lets figure out A and B now. 
   int A = (int) ((sum + squareSum) / 2);
   int B = squareSum - A;

   vector<int> ret;
   ret.push_back(A);
   ret.push_back(B);
   return ret;
}
```

Now, I wrote a similar code but without typecasting and it returned errors for larger inputs. Can anyone  explain how the typecasting solves the overflow?

Also, I saw the XOR method for this question but am unaware of bit manipulation problems. It would be great if someone could help me with some links/resources for handling questions using the bit manipulation approach!

Thanks for reading my problem and wanting to help! Cheers!

Comment: it's common for interview sites to have edge cases like very large values. make sure to always think about the range limits of each type.

Answer (score 1):

`(i + 1) * (i + 1)` would be evaluated in `int` arithmetic, with the potential for overflow, the behaviour of which is *undefined*.

Writing

```
((long long)(i + 1) * (long long)(i + 1));
```

is a long-winded way of obviating that effect; you could use the clearer

```
(i + 1LL) * (i + 1)
```

instead which causes conversion of the other terms.